# How to Add filter on the REST API Query to view the answers from QnAmaker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I'm using the following code in my chat bot (using v4 azure MS bot framework), to query the question and answers (Client side code - using plain JavaScript and J Query),

```
  function generateAnswer() 
  {
        var question = {
            question: "will you marry me"
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://YourEndPointURL/qnamaker/knowledgebases/eb895acb-e034-4f7c-asda7c-1955458ecec6/generateAnswer&$filter=source eq 'Editorial'",
            data: JSON.stringify(question),
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','EndpointKey c44444_Your_Endpoint_Key_4556');
            },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.answers[0].answer);   
            }
        });
    }
```

while using this code, i"m getting the following error response

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

So please help me with the **correct syntax to apply filter for my query.**

Comment: What do you Intent to get? QnA endpoint doesn't support query filter, please add your expected output. Do you want to get `Editorial` value?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron , thanks for replying, my intention is to get the answers only from a particular source in the knowledge base,  the expected output same as this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7GTj.png) , however when i have multiple sources in my knowledge base i should restrict the results / narrow down the results with only one source

Comment: So Its better to filter your result from response , but query filter is to supported for QnA maker request service. If I am not wrong you want just a single result right?

Comment: **Consider this Example** : when a user enter a question - what is your name  ?  the results is saved in two places i.e. Editorial source and mykb.xslx source, the bot now gives me the results from Editorial source only, but i want the results  from mykb.xslx only. Hope this will be clear, is there any way i can filter the source of results

Comment: When you would select your KB it should have request endpoint information like this POST /knowledgebases/KEY/generateAnswer Host: YourURL/qnamaker Authorization: EndpointKey YourKey Content-Type: application/json {"question":"<Your question>"} So it should give you response from your KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage, you need to specify filters in the body (the `data` property)

```
function generateAnswer() 
  {
        var data = {
            question: "will you marry me",
            strictFilters: [
            {
              "name": "source",
              "value": "Editorial"
            }],
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://YourEndPointURL/qnamaker/knowledgebases/eb895acb-e034-4f7c-asda7c-1955458ecec6/generateAnswer",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','EndpointKey c44444_Your_Endpoint_Key_4556');
            },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.answers[0].answer);   
            }
        });
    }
```

Moreover, you are missing 2 things:

1. your hostname, to replace `YourEndPointURL`
2. endpoint key, to replace `c44444_Your_Endpoint_Key_4556`

Comment: Hi,  thanks for replying.. I'm getting the following error code by trying your idea,                                    "{
  "error": {
    "code": "AzureSearchBadState",
    "message": "Strict filter (source) does not exist in the KB. Please retry with valid strict filters."
  }
}"

Comment: It's because it doesn't support query filter above answer is not correct. If you want to fetch `Editorial value` let me know.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron , Yes, i want to fetch editorial results alone in one scenario  and  another source in different scenario , please help me with the correct method.

Comment: My previous answer getting answer from my knowledge base I am wondering why I have to filter it again and What I have to filter I am confused now!

Comment: one knowledge base contains multiple sources (Editorial , Mycsutom Excel, qnamker chit chat..etc ), i want to query only one source  ( Mycsutom Excel)